# Adding time Strings in swift

Tags: ios, swift, loops, time, substring

I have an array of timeStrings of the following format:

x Hr(s) xx min.

I need to add these up to give a total. I'm wondering what is the best way to do this?

My thoughts were to find the index of "Hr(s)". Then if i substring between index 0 and the index of "Hr(s)", I have my hrs var and then add 6 to index of "Hr(s)" and find the index of "min" - 1, to give me the min var.

Then I need to take into account if seconds is greater than 60. So if I divide my seconds var by 60 and the answer is great than 1, I add that answer to my hrs var?

Can anyone see any flaws in this logic?

Sample implementation:

JSON response:

```
    {"status":"OK","hrs":[{"scheduleDate":"2015-11-09","userName":"John Doe","company":"Company X","hrsWorked":"0 Hr(s) 42 min"},{"scheduleDate":"2015-11-10","userName":"Jane Doe","company":"Company Y","hrsWorked":"0 Hr(s) 47 min"},{"scheduleDate":"2015-11-10","userName":"Bob loblaw","company":"Company X","hrsWorked":"0 Hr(s) 37 min"},{"scheduleDate":"2015-11-10","userName":"Joe Soap","company":"Company Y","hrsWorked":"0 Hr(s) 50 min"},{"scheduleDate":"2015-11-10","userName":"Test","company":"Company Y","hrsWorked":"0 Hr(s) 40 min"}],"queryStatus":"OK","message":null,"count":5}

var hrsVar = 0
var minsVar = 0
loop through hrsArray{
    hrsMinStr = hrsWorkedInJson
    if let endHrsIndex = hrsMinStr.lowercaseString.characters.indexOf("Hr(s)") {
        print("Index: \(index)")
        let hrsStr = Int(hrsMinStr.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: 0, end: endHrsIndex)))

        hrsVar += hrsStr

        let minStr = Int(hrsMinStr.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: endHrsIndex + 1, end: hrsMinStr.length - 3)))
        minsVar += minStr

    }
}

if minsVar/60 > 1 {
   hrsVar = hrsVar + minsVar/60
   minsVar = minsVar%60
}
```

**Update**

It seems as though I cannot pass in "Hr(s)" and instead only a single character "h". Because of this, I was trying to use the advancedBy(x) method to get the right endIndex. But I'm getting the error:

```
 Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<Index>' with an argument list of type '(start: Int, end: String.CharacterView.Index)'
```

Updated code:

```
if let endHrsIndex = hrsMinStr.lowercaseString.characters.indexOf("h") {
   print("Index: \(endHrsIndex)")
   let hrsStr = Int(hrsMinStr.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: 0, end: endHrsIndex)))

   hrsVar += hrsStr

   let minStr = Int(hrsMinStr.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: endHrsIndex.advancedBy(5), end: hrsMinStr.length.characters.count.advancedBy(-3))))
   minsVar += minStr
}
```

I'm really looking for the most efficient approach as possible, so please advise if there is a better way/if you see issues with this approach

Comment: In general, your logic looks fine and in place. Just wondering will you ever have the value of _minsVar_ being greater than 60 ? Would _hrsVar_ be + 1 in that case ?
Also, passing "time" values as numbers rather than strings is an approach that is more convenient than the one you currently use. It will spare you any headache with parsing and manipulating text values and transforming them back to actual time time representation.
If possible, try changing JSON _hrsWorked_ field to something like *hrsWorked = 1.5" which will stand for 1h 30m.. Much easier to handle...

Comment: Just as a different approach - you could convert the strings to NSDates with NSDateFormatter and compare with NSCalendar and then convert the difference back to a string. That takes away a need for doing your own math.

Comment: @VexyS the minsVar i.e. the parsed variable from the json will never be 60 or greater no. I don't think we would be able to change the JSON's response currently.

Comment: @Tim could you provide some sample code for passing the format of my string into NSDate and comparing? Is there any advantage for using that method?

Comment: @VexyS UPDATED question

Comment: Never mind on NSDate. I slightly misunderstood the question and it's more work here than many other good suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Foundation
let str = "0 Hr(s) 42 min"
let time = str
    .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("Hr(s)", withString:":")
    .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("min", withString: "")
    .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
let t = time.characters.split(Character(":"))
let h = Int(String(t[0])) // 0
let m = Int(String(t[1])) // 1
```

and sum

```
import Foundation

var time: [(hours:Int,minutes:Int,seconds:Int)] = []
for i in 0...5 {
    let h = Int(arc4random_uniform(24))
    let m = Int(arc4random_uniform(60))
    let s = Int(arc4random_uniform(60))
    time.append((h,m,s))
}
let t = time.reduce(0) { (sum, time: (hours: Int, minutes: Int, seconds: Int)) -> Int in
    sum + time.seconds + time.minutes * 60 + time.hours * 60 * 60
}


let seconds = t % 60
let minutes = ((t - seconds) / 60) % 60
let hours = ((t - seconds) / 3660)

time.forEach {
    print(String(format: "     %6d:%02d:%02d", arguments: [$0.hours,$0.minutes, $0.seconds]))
}
print("-------------------")
print(String(format: "Sum: %6d:%02d:%02d", arguments: [hours,minutes,seconds]))
/*

         12:25:04
          2:43:36
         14:09:35
         11:59:43
         10:39:19
         23:32:14
-------------------
Sum:     74:29:31

*/
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the first method I've got working. I hadn't thought of replacing strings and splitting! With regard, the second part of your answer, My string does not include seconds, could it be modified to account for that?

Comment: create tuple from minutes and hours. you can modify the code easy

Comment: I'm accepting based off the first part of the answer. I will stick to my own logic for the second part

Answer (score 0):

You should most likely try using the scanners in your case.

```
        let string = "12 Hr(s) 37 min"
        let scanner = NSScanner(string: string)
        var min: Int = 0
        var hour : Int = 0
        scanner.scanInteger(&hour)
        scanner.scanString("Hr(s) ", intoString: nil)
        scanner.scanInteger(&min)
```

Or even easier if you create this part in Objective-C:

```
        int min, hour;
        sscanf("12 Hr(s) 37 min", "%d Hr(s) %d min", &hour, &min);
```

Comment: I've never worked with scanners before, excuse my ignorance. Can you give a sample of how to get the hr and min var out of the string?

Comment: Is the example I gave you not doing exactly that?

Comment: I tought that was objective C. I've gone for the replaceString and split approach as I can understand it better

Comment: The first example is in Swift and the second is Objective-C. Both do the same.